# Add-Type / PowerShell 7+: No wildcard accepted for -AssemblyName parameter

Tags: powershell, wildcard, powershell-7.2

The [Microsoft documentation on `Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type#parameters) claims that the `AssemblyName` parameter accepts wildcards.

However, when I try using `Add-Type -AssemblyName '*SqlServer.Smo'` in PowerShell Core, it doesn't work. I get the error message: "`Add-Type: Cannot load assembly '*.SqlServer.Smo'`":

[image: PowerShell Add-Type]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It only resolves _trailing_ wildcards, eg. `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.SqlServer.S??`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - The documentation gives an example with a leading wildcard. Perhaps there's no assembly present that matches the given wildcard, or the assembly is defective/incompatible in some way?

Comment: The example given depicts that the assembly can be loaded when not using a wildcard. So, the assembly is present.

Comment: I created a corresponding issue on GitHub: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17529

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that's not true, `Add-Type -As *m.W*s.F*s` works to load `System.Windows.Forms`